# Помощь в настройке PHPStorm

Tags: ide, веб-сервер, php, phpstorm

Доброго времени суток.

Набрал код на PHPStorm 8, запустил в Firefox, а там Bad Gateway 502, посмотрел туториалы настройки, и вот тут возникли непонятки. Например, пишу тот же код в SublimeText2, врубаю OpenServer, открываю текстовый файл в Firefox, и все работает, а здесь ничего понять не могу. Одни говорят поставь Yii Framework, xDebug, куча непонятных слов, и еще я не понял, OpenServer станет ненужным после правильной настройки PHPStorm? И почему PHPSTorm просит интерпретатор указать? Например, в VisualStudio он был встроенный, и нужен ли вообще для PHPStorm веб-сервер? Если так, то подойдет ли OpenServer? Как их подружить? В общем, прошу помощи с настройкой PHPStorm, ибо сам не разобрался, и слишком много непонятных для меня вещей. Заранее благодарю.

Comment: Все! Спасибо, если кто просматривал, разобрался. )

Comment: @Mahdi735, По возможности публикуйте ответы на форуме, они могут помочь многим в будущем.

Comment: Так и сделаю

Answer (score 1):

Вообщем, если набегут такие же новички может кому будет нужно, в `openserver` я сделал так:

1. Настройки-закладки-указать на exe файл phpstorm;
2. Сохранить и запустить phpstorm через opensever (ссылка на exe файл phpstorm появится в закладках после перезапуска openserver);
3. phpstorm запустившись из под openserver автоматом предложит интепретатор php, который уже есть в комплекте openserver (там же есть и встроенный xdebug).

Ну и все, дальше сохранив файл с php кодом надо запустить в браузере и все работает, никаких bad gateway 502, я еще многого могу не понимать, если что-то не верно, прошу подправить.

Comment: @Mahdi735 Отредактировал ваш ответ.